# Content hides under appbar layout

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

In my app contet is hidden under appbarlayout. I don't expect that behaviour!

**Android 23 PREVIEW**

[image]

**ANDROID 21 - test on DEVICE**

[image]

**ANDROID 21 - test on DEVICE content hidden under toolbar**

[image]

Altough my content scroll down as expect, when it goes up content is hidden under toolbar. I uploaded also android 23 preview because there is visible that actually toolbar is align Top behind status bar. Working on device content go up where is should be moved if the preview was correct. But toolbar view is under status bar not behind. I dont know where is the problem.

*Style*

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoStatusBar" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
</style>
```

**UPDATED**

ok I found the solution. It was so dump. Just my scrollView was scrolled down due to its last child which was gaining focus - recycler view.
No I set on cardView focusableInTouchMode="true" and the last element on false

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:fillViewport="true">

 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        app:contentPaddingTop="24dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

...
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/recycler_view_overbid_history"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:maxHeight="200dp"
       android:focusable="false"
       android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```

android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

Answer (score 1):

I'm sharing part of my code with you, it's working for me in my app:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="140dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.75">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/store_detail_background"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            ...

        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

v21/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/...</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    ...
</style>
```